# iOS: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoalumberjack

I'm trying to implement CocoaLumberjack as framework and it works fine on the simulator but when try to use it on my iPhone I'm getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3EF12D55/myApp.app/CocoaLumberjackSample
  Reason: image not found
```

Any of you knows why the difference between the simulator and the device?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the difference is simple:

Whenever you run your app in simulator it can access any other build products in the same build folder, e.g., frameworks. That's why you do not experience this problem in simulator. On your iOS device that is different story because Xcode only copies the actual app bundle to your device. So in order to make it work you need to add CocoaLumberjack.framework to the `Embed Frameworks` build phase. This will copy the framework into the `Frameworks` subfolder in the app bundle so that your app binary can find it.

[image]

If you do not have the `Embed Frameworks` build phase you can either add a `New Copy Files Build Phase` via the add button in the top left of the build phases tab and then select `Frameworks` as destination. The other option is to select the General tab, scroll down and then add your framework under the `Embedded Binaries` section.

Comment: How do you add the option for Embed FrameWorks in Xcode 8.3.1?

Comment: You can either add a new Copy Build Phase via the add button in the top left of the build phases tab and then select `Frameworks` as destination. The other option is to select the General tab, scroll down and then add your framework under the `Embedded Binaries` section.

Comment: I did the same and it got fixed but now I am getting 90085 error while uploading build to app store connect